# NodeJS MVC - NoSQL Best Practices

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, nosql

I want to ask what is the best approach for the next hypothetical situation:

Let's say that I have a Node app written with a NoSQL DB(Mongo) where I have just one collection: **users**
The documents in this collection have a subdocument named for example **articles**.
And because is an MVC approach we have a controller and a service for this collection.
Now, if the code in the controller and the service files is very long (>1000 lines of code in each), is it a good practice to split the logic in two separates folder, each with it's own controller and service, given the fact that they are connected at the same collection in the same database? Instead of having just **user** to have **user** and **articles**, both connected to same collection.

What are your thoughts on this?